# In AngularJS, why does putting presentation logic (such as jQuery) into controllers negatively affect testability?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to Angular and to coding from a 'testing' mindset.  I understand that putting presentation logic into controllers is not the 'Angular Way,' but don't understand why it negatively affects testability.

Comment: that is a good question. I often wondered myself, but I do follow the rule. It should be in a directive, because you can compile a directive and test it.

Answer (score 4):

Because it puts a reliance on there being a DOM to test. You should be able to test controller logic without needing to create a DOM because you should just be mocking the dependencies and then testing the data in the constructed view model.

Testing aside, controllers job in life is to marshal data, they do not know about views, all they know about is a view model and they should only call backend services and then shape that data to be presented to the view. If you are doing anymore than that in your controllers you are not following the design pattern properly.

If you find yourself writing business logic in controller you should think about refactoring that logic out into services. Controllers should be nice and lean, only marshalling the flow of data between services and the view model.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it should be in a directive because you can test that easily with a unit test with a fragment of HTML being compiled. I hope someone has a better answer than that.